# WCF Service - Endpoint is not showing

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF Service where it has one endpoint and I have the service contract and operation contract setup in the config file but when I run the service, it cannot find the endpoint although I configured it in the web.config.

This service will be setup in IIS so I have no base address setup.

The ServiceContract has a configuration name of agent_port_type and the service behavior has a configuration name of agent_service.  I am using basicHttpBinding.

Below is a copy of part of my config file:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ETAOutboundServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"  httpsGetEnabled="true"  />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="Metadata">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"  httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ETAOutboundServiceBehavior" name="agent_service">
        <clear />
        <endpoint address="" name="agent_interface" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="agent_port_type"
          listenUriMode="Explicit" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"
          listenUriMode="Explicit" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I had it working on a different service fine but then I used svcutil to create agent_port_type and it is not working.

Comment: AFAIK you still neet to provide an address for the endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try simplifying the config to something that Works, then add extra options as need.

Start With:

- Remove Clear tag
- Remove all References to HTTPS
- Remove listenURIMode
- Add an address for the endpoint
- Check the IIS log that you are calling the service that you think you are calling
- Add a syntax error to Your config and check that it fails (to make sure that the config file you are editing is the one being used)